# Cannot get WAV files to play

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to get a WAV clip to play and am having some issues. Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class NewClass { 
private File soundFile = new File("/Project/src/model/soundfile.wav");

public NewClass() {

    JLabel playArea = new JLabel();
    playArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        AudioClip clip = null;
        try {
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip(soundFile.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    clip.play();    
    });
}
```

I have a separate folder (model) within the src folder that I have any images or in this case WAV files kept in (I know my MVC isn't right, but that a problem for another day). It runs without any exceptions, but just doesn't play anything. I've used this same code snippit in another project I wrote a while ago and it worked, so I'm stuck on why its all messed up now. Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you know it runs without exceptions since your only catching MalformedURLException? Also, clip.play should be inside of the try block. Otherwise when you do get an exception and clip is null your going to get a secondary null reference exception.

Comment: Are you waiting for the play to finish somewhere? If your program stops immediately after calling `play` you will get little or no music.

Comment: jaket - You're right, I don't know that it isn't throwing any other exceptions, I'm using eclipse as my IDE and the try/catches were generated automatically by it. I tried putting clip.play() inside the try block, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Again, I cut and pasted this code from another program I used it in, where it worked fine. This makes me think its something in the file path, but I'm not sure.

Comment: greg-449 - My program isn't stopping right after, the code I posted above is actually part of a larger class, I just only showed the audio part, sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: So make a test to see whether or not the file address is working, yes? If not working, show us the file structure. Also, I'd seriously consider using Clip instead of AudioClip. The API is a lot more developed, and you can consult the Java Tutorials, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

Comment: I'm not trying to self promote here, but I wrote some code for this a long time ago. I don't know what's wrong with yours, but heres the link anyway. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9bp92thgibb0pft/AAAFXUyR90K1fKHWrqUggwU3a?dl=0

Comment: @user3226170 As for file paths, do some testing with it, make sure that you are using the **correct** path, but also try some `C:/Users/<user>/<path-to-code>` too.

Answer (score 0):

So I switched over to the Clip class instead of AudioClip and got it working. Here's the code that did it for me:

```
File pop;

try {
        pop = new File(StartView.class.getResource("/model/pop.wav")
                .toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

void playSound(File soundIn) {   // Use pop as the input argument

        File soundFile = soundIn;
        AudioInputStream sound = null;

        try {
            sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,
                sound.getFormat());
        clip = null;
        try {
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            clip.open(sound);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clip.start();
}
```

I can't say why the previous code wasn't working, but switching to Clip seems to have done the trick.